# Why Doesn't Prepared Statement Seem to Bind Result (again)?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, prepared-statement, prepare

I am a PHP/MySQL rookie. I'm working on authentication, but my code does not allow me to get to the right page.   Here's what I have:

```
    <?php
$username = null;
$password = null;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    require_once('database.php');

    if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = ? and user_password = PASSWORD(?)");
        $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($userid);
        $query->fetch();
        $query->close();

        if(!empty($userid)) {
// Stuff happens
} else {
// goes back to the login page
```

At this point, $userid seems to be empty, 'cause I keep going back to the login page. The database.php is just the connection, and I have confimed that this is okay.  I have also confirmed that the form properly submits $_POST["username"] and $_POST["password"], and the code above creates $username and $password.  I can echo those to see the correct results. The field names in the database match the field names in the SQL statement.  But for some reason, $userid is empty.  I've read other posts, but I barely understand what I'm doing, let alone what others are doing or explaining.  I think this is something very basic, but what is it?

Comment: How do you store the password of the user? You should use a good hash function with a lot of salt. You shouldn't definitively not use MySQLs PASSWORD(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function. I cite from the description: **Note** _The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider MD5() or SHA2() instead._ But of course you shouldn't consider MD5() at all, because it's broken.

Comment: I'm sorry, VMai, but you're over my head.  I'll study your response and, hopefully, understand it somewhere down the road.  I did find the answer, though (which I think is what you were trying to tell me).  Thanks much!

Comment: First you should not use PASSWORD() in your application. Not for storing and not for reading password. Second: please don't store plain text password, but use the hashing function sha2(). Last: [Wikipedia on salt in cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Answer (score 0):

Why is that PASSWORD()?

```
    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = ? and user_password = ?");
    $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($userid);
    $query->fetch();
    $query->close();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it! I got that PASSWORD(?) from another site (http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/05/creating-a-simple-to-do-application-%E2%80%93-part-3/).  I didn't understand it, and didn't question it.  I thought it was security thing. I didn't understand the prepared statement, but after studying it more, I'm starting to get it.

Thanks so much!!